# getting status 405 in java post to api

Tags: java, post, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to make a post to my api from a java application, but i'm getting status 405. It works fine if i do it from Postman, so the error is my call.

The code is:

```
HttpPost requestGen = new HttpPost(URI); 
StringEntity paramsGen = new StringEntity(resultGlobal);
requestGen.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
requestGen.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
requestGen.setEntity(paramsGen);
HttpResponse responseGen = httpClientGen.execute(requestGen);
```

The response is:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED [Connection: keep-alive, Content-Type: text/html, Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, Content-Length: 178, Server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/3.6.3, Date: Fri, 15 Dec 2017 02:30:07 GMT, Via: 1.1 vegur] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html,Content-Length: 178,Chunked: false]}}
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: a 405 almost always means you're calling a route that's correct but with an unsupported verb. Are you sure it's a POST vs. a PUT or related?

Comment: @Joe is solved, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse was adding an extra / in the URI, now it works !

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the 'Allow' header in the response which says 'OPTIONS','GET','HEAD'.
So Probably
- > You are hitting a different resource from your JS compared to POSTMAN.
   Keep the Network tab open in Devtools of your browser to view what you are hitting.If you still cannot figure it out, post the screenshot of Network tab here.